# Outline not available for Spock tests in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, spock

I am working on a Java project in Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 14.04. I use Spock to test my code. I have the Groovy Eclipse plugin 2.0, Spock 0.7 jar and JUnit 4 jar.

The Outline View is not available for the Spock test files. Nevertheless the Ctrl-O shortcut is working fine.

[image: outline not available]

How can I make the Outline view working?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Groovy and/or Spock plugins installed in your Eclipse? Each language-specific plugin has to contribute to Outline in order for it to render, but I'm not sure if the Groovy plugin implements the Outline view.

Comment: Yes I have the Groovy plugin, and the Spock Jar. But it is weird that the Ctrl-O shortcut (which basically shows the outline) works correctly.

Comment: Is the problem specific to Spock? What happens for a JUnit test written in Groovy?

Comment: I still cannot see the outline for a JUnit test written in Groovy

Comment: Then the problem is unrelated to Spock :-)